# Accessing JSON Response From Webservice

Tags: javascript, json

I need to access a property `api_status` from a json webservice response,and check if it is equal to "00", in order to carry out some conditional code,

The response is:

```
{
  "result": "true",
  "msg": "Error!Wrong Access",
  "data": {
    "api_status": {
      "0": "00"
    }
  }
}
```

My code for accessing the response is

```
 var data_array = $.parseJSON(resp);
 if(data_array.data.api_status == "00")
 {//do some code}
```

The issue is that i cant access the `api_status` property using this method.
How can i access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_array.data.api_status` would get you back the object:

```
{
    "0": "00"
}
```

So you still need to go one level deeper.  Try:

```
data_array.data.api_status["0"]
```

---

The variable name `data_array` is also a little confusing because there is no array in the JSON object that you posted.